# Is it possible to maintain backward compatibility with DynamicType in protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, deserialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

We recently made the decision to update the version of protobuf-net used in some projects.

With the update we noticed that the Dynamic Type feature was discontinued.

We would like to continue using the new features, but we need to continue deserializing the data that had already been serialized using DynamicType.

Is there any way to reconcile the two? Any custom serializer to maintain backwards compatibility?

Has anyone else gone through this?

We've already tried to create a custom serializer, but we haven't been able to make much progress. We always end up running into errors due to the failure of some resource that is not exposed in the package.